Could not connect trough sshpass with password saved in variable
I'm trying to connect to the server via ssh with password I've saved to variable SSHPASS.
sshpass -p "$SSHPASS" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@address

And it resulted with
Permission denied, please try again.

There's no issue if I type in password manually trough ssh.

It looks like the issue might be related to how the SSHPASS variable is being passed or handled by the sshpass command.
Ensure SSHPASS is properly set: Verify that the SSHPASS variable is actually set with the correct password by echoing it:
echo "$SSHPASS"

If the password is correct and being echoed properly, you can check for special characters in the password.
If your password contains special characters (e.g., !, $, etc.), they may be misinterpreted by the shell.
In that case, try escaping the characters or wrapping the password in single quotes when setting the variable like this :
SSHPASS='password'

I hope this will help you.
